# Display number with 4 decimal places

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv

I'm trying to display 100.1230 with 4 decimal places but the number gets displayed as 100.123 removing trailing zero in CSV file and displays 100.1234 with 4 decimal places intact. I'd like to achieve this in SQLite possibly

Comment: Just change the `.2f` to `.4f`

Comment: Did you look at the duplicate? It shows how to display a number in 2 decimal places in SQLite, if you take the most upvoted answer you would replace `.2f` in the code with `.4f`

Comment: Still it removes the trailing zero in the CSV file even after transforming the number

Comment: That must be a function of what is writing to the CSV file. I suggest opening a new question and providing **all** of the details on how you are generating the values and writing them to the file, and then it might be possible to figure out what is going on. If for some reason you can't ask a new question, send me another message and I'll reopen this one, but either way you will need to add a lot more info.

Comment: CSV file displays 100.1230 as 100.123 I applied .4f as suggested in Python but it fixes the column correctly but also affects the adjacent integer column by adding a trailing 04 to the number unnecessarily even if the specific column is specified df['col1']=df['col1'].map('${:,.4f}'.format)

Comment: As I said, I think you should open a new question. If you can't, edit this one with enough information to explain the problem and I'll reopen it.

Comment: I need to display number with 4 decimals in CSV file even for the numbers with trailing zeros such as 100.1230 as 100.1230 and not as 100.123 using any program and not manually. That's my original question. There's nothing more to add.

Comment: Of course there is. Most importantly, **show some code**. Give some sample data and show how you expect it to appear in the file, and what you actually get.